# Resize DataGrid Column OnLoaded programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, column-width

I have this DataGrid which looks like this when I load data for the first time:
[image]

so, its almost perfect but what I really want is shown when I resize the Window to maximum - the columns are now layouted like this:
[image]

I would like to layout the right most columns at the right part of the DataGrid view and have the left column allocate the rest of the view.

My question is: Can I invoke an event on the DataGrid to cause this layouting of the columns that would otherwise only occur when the Window is maximized?

The simplified version of the DataGrid's XAML looks like this:

```
<DataGrid
   ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
   ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
   GridLinesVisibility="None"
   ColumnWidth="*">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="Name">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <Grid>
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                       <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                  Text="{Binding ItemName}"
                                  ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="true"
                                  >
                        </TextBlock>
                   </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Size">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock
                       Text="{Binding ItemLengthA}"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                              Margin="3,0,0,0"
                   />
               </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto" Header="Modified">
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <TextBlock
                       Text="{Binding ItemLastUpdateA}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       Margin="3,0,0,0"
                   />
               </DataTemplate>
           </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I also have working application/control to inspect [here](https://github.com/Dirkster99/Aehnlich/blob/master/source/AehnlichViewLib/Controls/DiffDirView.xaml) but I think looking at the above XAML should be enough to find a solution based on the given layout.

Comment: The code seems all right to me. I had tested a similar `DataGrid` with some data, it just keep showing like your secend picture whatever how size was changed. So maybe some other thing was effected the layout.

Comment: Do you host you DataGrid inside a window with SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" or SizeToContent="Width" ? I experienced this kind of behaviour when window adapts to content width.

Comment: The Window code is just standard code as you would get it if you create a new WPF project - no special things there. There are some other things like scroll synchronization and RowStyle Background Color customization that I can try to turn off to see if the behavior changes but until now I did not think it would matter ... I'll check if turning things off changes the Column width behavior...

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to reproduce your case and came to the result: It depends on how you will the ItemsSource. 
In case ItemsSource in ViewModel  is a List, then you can just Assign a new instance to it, and call the PropertyChanged Event. This will cause the columns to behave like you want (Width="Auto").

```
      ItemsSource = new List<Data>();
      // ItemsSource.Add(new Data()); // ..adding data 
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ItemsSource)));
```

However, as it's currently not working, I guess that you have maybe a ObservableCollection as ItemsSource, and you are adding Items there.  In my tests, it behaves as you descriped, columns stay small, unless resizing of the Window oder the columns manually.

```
  public ObservableCollection<Data> ItemsSource { get; set; }
  public void AddItems()
  {
      ItemsSource.Add(new Data()); // not working
  }
```

The only way I've found to force the grid to do it, was, to Unset the Column Width from Auto to some value, and then back. Is used a button to do this. but Any Onload would also work

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridTemplateColumn item in MyDataGrid.Columns)
        {
            if (item.Width.IsAuto)
            {
                item.Width = new DataGridLength(item.ActualWidth, item.Width.UnitType);
                item.Width = DataGridLength.Auto;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can verify your findings - I can also reproduce the same wanted behavior with the ObservableCollection<> - it looks like its not the type of collection but the fact that an existing collection is really replaced with a new collection followed by a PropertyChanged event that makes this work.

The ObservableCollection actually sends a NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset but that does not seem to be reasonable enough for the Grid to actually lay out the items correctly. So, the solution is now to always reconstruct the entire (Observable) collection on every reload... thanks for the hint :-)